# Filtering a table with any combination of several search criteria

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've made a list of bars for my friends/coworkers and I want to add a tool that allows them to search for bars that match their preferred criteria.

The google sheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yuvzEVfrmhpa22Z9wDB8B7s_wxm4rGbGSn6nGMCitXo/edit?usp=sharing).

I want the user to be able to search based on the criteria they input on the left under "keywords". So this many be anywhere from 1, keyword to all 7 filled out. But I want it to search based on any combination.

I initially started with an `INDEX/MATCH` formula which only returned a single row.

I landed on the `FILTER` function after trying different options.
However, this does not ignore blank search terms. Cell D4 on the Search page has the current formula. This will filter by Area, and then Area and Category if both are filled out, but I have yet to figure out how to expand this to the remaining filters. 
My current function is the following:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(LEN(B6),LEN(B7)),FILTER(AllInfo,Area=B6,Category=B7),FILTER(AllInfo,Area=B6)),"-")
```

The filter function does exactly what I want for one search criteria, but my attempts to include any combination of search terms have failed.

I have a number of named data ranges which reference their respective columns on the 'Toronto - BARS' sheet.

Feel free to share this list with any friends living in Toronto!

Edit: removed irrelevant information

Comment: What, exactly, is your problem?

Comment: as far as I understood, the problem is that the current function only takes into account the first two filters, and not all of them.

Comment: Yes I want all the filters to be considered when listing the results. I also want blank filters to be ignored. Maybe this would be easier with an google app script function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I got is the formula below, which requires you to replace the boolean values into "yes" and "no" (or any other string values):

```
=ArrayFormula(query({AllInfo},"select * "&if(counta(B6:B12)>0,"where ",)&join(" and ","Col"&(match(filter(A6:A12,B6:B12<>""), transpose('Toronto - BARS'!A1:I1),0))&"='"&filter(B6:B12, B6:B12<>"")&"'"),0))
```

2 improvements that could be made, but I didn't figure it out:

- using the column names in the query, instead of column number
- parsing the boolean values correctly and add or remove the single quotes accordingly, so it can support the current boolean values / checkboxes

==> I hope someone can pick that up and finish what I couldn't get done.

Comment: Thank you! I will play around with this and let you know where I end up!

Comment: This is working great! (I tried upvoting as well but since I'm new it's not showing up for you) I switched the boolean values to be "Yes" and "No" and so far it appears all the keywords are working except for the pool/games option.

I'm not too familiar with the query function so I'm going see if I can understand what you've done here. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Right, I forgot about it in my explanation above, but I renamed the column to match exactly the name of the filter, so each filter can dynamically apply to the right column. Was cleaner than hard-coding the filters imo. So you should ensure each filter has the same label / name as the corresponding column, and it will work.

Comment: Thank you very much Benoit! Looks like I need to touch up on the query function. Cheers!

Comment: Benoit thanks for all your help! I've Linked your stack overflow in the credits for this sheet. Hope that is ok.

Comment: wasn't necessary, but still appreciated. And you're very welcome.