# Google Sheets - FILTER show all if no criteria is selected

Tags: google-sheets

Need your help with the following workaround.

So I have data set and multiple criteria (9) in a drop-down mode which I easily FILTER but am stuck in the situation when one of the FILTER is necessary and nothing is selected in a drop-down list. How I can tell the FILTER function, that if nothing is selected in the criteria, just ignore that criteria without writing long IF (9x9 combination) statements and FILTER just with the filters which are selected (from the drop-down list)?

This is the formula I'm using now.

```
=FILTER(data,marketplace=$C$3,
propertytype=$C$4,
bedroom=$C$5,
bathroom=$C$6,
minsqft=$C$7,
maxsqft=$C$8,
year=$C$9,
pool=$C$10,
postpossession=$C$11)
```

Comment: Use `QUERY()` with `LIKE` operator using wild card `%`. Share a sample google-sheet so that we can put formula for you. Also put your current formula to your post.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QU_g_dFeI3W2Fuw3FD8m_cHUv4lEXRttkF2QjoZxiXQ/edit?usp=sharing - here is the sample data. At this moment I'm using only FILTER function.

Comment: I found not full but a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529884/filtering-a-table-with-any-combination-of-several-search-criteria - the only problem is, that this formula takes into account only first two filters. here's the formula: =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(query({data},"select * "&if(counta(C3:C11)>0,"where ",)&JOIN(" and ","Col"&(match(filter(B3:B11,C3:C11<>""), transpose(Raw_Data!A1:Q1),0))&"='"&filter(C3:C11, C3:C11<>"")&"'"),0),"-"))

Comment: sheet is private

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost a year old now, but I'll answer for anyone else who might need this:

You can use ARRAYFORMULA with your filter criteria to essentially apply the criteria when a filter is selected, or ignore it when it isn't.

For a range in A2:D25, and filters in G2:G4:

```
=FILTER(
  A2:D25,
  ARRAYFORMULA((A2:A25 = G2) + (G2 = "") > 0),
  ARRAYFORMULA((B2:B25 = G3) + (G3 = "") > 0),
  ARRAYFORMULA((C2:C25 = G4) + (G4 = "") > 0)
)
```

Here we use `+` to basically say "match when one thing OR the other is true". This is akin to when people multiply criteria together because they want to AND the criteria together.

Here's a spreadsheet that demos it. You can look at the formula in cell J1. If you want to modify it to test it, go to File -> Make a Copy to create your own duplicate.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFZ0a2RiY03KlrovJ4egBlapoYjErO-yIhBBT3xRGJY/edit#gid=0